# With OIDC can an administrator obtain an access token for a different, regular user?

Tags: openid-connect, identity, claims-based-identity

I have a scenario where a special server would like to be able to request certain claims (from an IdP) about any regular user, whenever needed.  This happens off-line, so the user may not be present and it is not practical to store the credentials for all users in this special server.  What I was hoping was that the special server could obtain a "super" access token once every few months (very infrequently based on long token expiration times and/or automatic renewal), when it was convenient for the human administrator, and that the super-token could be used to obtain particular user claims whenever needed.  This is a super-protected server, so some usual security concerns are not present.  So far, I don't see this as being allowed/supported by OIDC.

Answer (score 1):

You are free to create impersonation within the OAuth specs.

OpenID Connect does not offer any guidance about impersonation. But it is a part of [OAuth 2.0](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-token-exchange-14#section-4.1).

> The "act" (actor) claim provides a means within a JWT to express that
> delegation has occurred and identify the acting party to whom
> authority has been delegated.

Using this `act` claim, your token payload will look like:

```
{
      "aud":"https://consumer.example.com",
      "iss":"https://issuer.example.com",
      "exp":1443904177,
      "nbf":1443904077,
      "sub":"user@example.com",
      "act":
      {
        "sub":"admin@example.com"
      }
    }
```

Where `act.sub` is the current actor.

Comment: Unfortunately in my scenario, it is not practical for every user to delegate to an admin.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your desires, you should Use the Standards based [User_Managed Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-Managed_Access)

UMA is an OAuth-based access management protocol standard. Version 1.0 of the standard was approved by the Kantara Initiative on March 23, 2015

Comment: Even with UMA, if I am reading it correctly, each individual must initially set some access or delegation.  In my scenario, it is not practical to get every user to do that.  And not practical for an admin to do it for every single user (unless the admin could do it with a script and would not have to know each user's credentials).